# How can you know the length of the byte-array to deserialize using protobuf-net?

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I am trying to send a C# object from one process to another using a Memory-Mapped File, and I am trying to use either BinaryFormatter or protobuf-net. Neither is working - apparently because I am using by necessity a fixed-length byte-array and protobuf-net needs an array that is exactly the correct length?

Using protobuf-net, I get this exception on Deserialize: "ProtoException: 'Unconsumed data left in the buffer; this suggests corrupt input'
at the line: "message1 = Serializer.Deserialize(memoryStream);

Here is my code. At this point I'm just trying a simple example in order to get it to work at a basic level:
This is the object that I want to send between programs:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class IpcMessage
{
    public IpcMessage() { }

    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string title { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember( 2 )]
    public string content { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the (simplified - I removed the synchronization) code that sends the IpcMessage object:

```
static void SampleSend()
{
    // Create the memory-mapped file which allows 'Reading' and 'Writing'
    using (MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateOrOpen( "MyMmfName", 1024, MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite ))
    {
        // Create a view-stream for this process, which allows us to write data from offset 0 to 1024 (whole memory)
        using (MemoryMappedViewStream mmvStream = mmf.CreateViewStream( 0, 1024))
        {
            IpcMessage message1 = new IpcMessage();
            message1.title = "test";
            message1.content = "hello world";
            Serializer.Serialize( mmvStream, message1 );
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the code in the receiving program (simplified a bit):

```
// Create the memory mapped file..
using (MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateOrOpen( "MyMmfName", 1024, MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite ))
{
    using (MemoryMappedViewAccessor mmvStream = mmf.CreateViewAccessor( 0, 1024, MemoryMappedFileAccess.Read ))
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        IpcMessage message1;
        int numberBytesRead = mmvStream.ReadArray<byte>( 0, buffer, 0, 1024 );
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(buffer);
        // It is at this next line that I get ProtoException: 'Unconsumed data left in the buffer; this suggests corrupt input'
        message1 = Serializer.Deserialize<IpcMessage>( memoryStream );
    }
}
```

When I was trying to use BinaryFormatter it complained also. Clearly I am doing something very basically wrong.

Looking thru other questions - I see that most implementations seem to have a byte-array that is allocated to just the right length. Here, I don't know the length ahead of time -- it is just a fixed-length 1024-byte array (I chose this size arbitrarily, just for now). Or perhaps it's something obvious that I'm missing?

This is my first time to use a Memory-Mapped File, or protobuf-net. Any help or advice is appreciated - thank you in advance.

Note: I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise 15.9.6, and this code is targeting .NET Framework 4.0

Comment: In most .NET libraries, the serialization creates a buffer the size it needs, and when receiving data, you can either read until the stream ends or pre-check the size of the stream. Why are you using predefined 1024B arrays without at least checking if you need to increase the size?

Comment: Thanks for responding Danny. The receiving code is in a different program, and it does not know how big the stream (or the byte-array) needs to be, until it has deserialized the object, because that object has string fields. I chose to make the buffer 1024 bytes just to make it large enough for this simple example but there's no reason I can't make it larger. The IpcMessage object is definitely not needing a larger buffer however.

Comment: James, when reading from a stream you can check if the length is readable, if so you know how large the bugger needs to be, if not you can start with a reasonable size and replace with a buffer twice as big each time you are about to pass the current length.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Option 1: tell `MemoryStream` the correct number of bytes to use in the optional constructor overload; this will work for all serializers.

Option 2, specifically for protobuf-net: use `ProtoReader`; the `Deserialize` API accepts a `Stream` **or** a `ProtoReader`; the latter can be constructed with a notional length and will not over-read

Option 3, again protobuf-net: use the `*WithLengthPrefix` APIs for serialize and deserialize

Note that any option assumes that your code can robustly determine the length, which should usually be communicated separately in whatever "framing" approach you're using. Option 3 deals with this internally, but in many scenarios your own code still needs to be frame-aware so that you don't consume too much and read I to the next message (unless this is UDP with exactly one frame per packet, but... it isn't, because `MemoryMappedFile`). You also need to consider what happens if a payload is larger than the expected buffer size.

The simplest way of "framing" would be to reserve 4 bytes at the start of each logical block; serialize starting at offset 4, and then write the number of bytes written back in at offsets 0-thru-3, using fixed 4-byte layout in your choice of endianness (usually "little"). When reading: read the first 4 bytes to get the length, then consume that- many bytes from the segment. This is essentially what `*WithLengthPrefix` does internally, except a few different layout options are supported.

Comment: Marc - thank you for your most-excellent answer. I had started that very thing - the first 4 bytes to indicate the length.
But the problem is actually somewhere else: When run as a separate program, it works fine. But as a Windows Service -- it is not receiving anything in the Memory-Mapped-File (MMF)!
I named the Mutex  with the prefix "Global\", and the other program could see it. But I found that the MMF itself, is not visible!

Apparently because Windows Services are placed within their own Session. Thus the need to include "Global\"  in the names. But even that didn't work here.

Comment: @JamesHurst sounds fun - good luck working throught that - the global prefix *should* have worked...